# Function which finds identical sets of rows when comparing specified columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to write a T-SQL function that can test for the presence of a duplicated set of rows in a table in which some columns are compared and some are ignored.

For example, consider the following data set:

```
BomID   PartNumber  ItemNumber  Quantity    UnitID
4164    10004001    10001419        1         33
4169    10004001    103599          1         33
4171    10004001    103601          1         33
4163    10004001    10001329       10         33
4166    10004001    101823          8         33
10794   10012161    10001419        1         33
10799   10012161    103599          1         33
10801   10012161    103601          1         33
10793   10012161    10001329       10         33
10796   10012161    101823          8         33
```

I would like to write a function `Bom.f_GetPartsThatHaveAnIdenticalBom(partNumber)` which when passed **10004001** can efficiently detect that **10012161** has duplicate records as determined by comparing the tuple `(ItemNumber, Quantity, UnitID)`.  The key field **BomID** is ignored.  So the function would return the distinct list of part numbers (if any) that have identical BOMs.

I've done this operation manually using various techniques. But since I seem to be needing this routine ever more frequently, I would like to have a function that is set-based, highly efficient, and which can be composed with other tables in LINQ to Entities queries.

Answer (score 2):

The following query uses a `full outer join` to compare the two sets.  Any records that do not match will result in NULL values on one side or the other.  The comparison in the `having` clause filters these out.

```
SELECT b1.PartNumber, b2.PartNumber AS TargetPartNumber
FROM bom b full outer join
     bom b2
     ON b1.ItemNumber = b2.ItemNumber AND
        b1.Quantity = b2.Quantity and
        b1.UnitID = b2.UnitID and
        b1.PartNumber <> b2.PartNumber
WHERE b1.PartNumber = @PartNumber
GROUP BY b1.PartNumber, b2.PartNumber
having count(*) = count(b1.PartNumber) and
       count(*) = count(b2.PartNumber)
```

You might be able to make this more efficient by having an index on (itemnumber, quantity, unitid, partnumber).

Comment: Thanks.  This approach is unfortunately returning a lot of false positives. Removing the non-matched records is not the point of my query. I seek to discover any target part numbers which contain all BOM-items-tuples in common with the specified source part number's BOM.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a SQL statement that may work for you.

```
DECLARE @PartNumber int = 10004001

SELECT DISTINCT bom2.TargetPartNumber
FROM
    (
    SELECT PartNumber, COUNT(*) AS ItemCount
    FROM bom
    WHERE PartNumber = @PartNumber
    GROUP BY PartNumber
    ) AS bom1
JOIN
    (
    SELECT b1.PartNumber, b2.PartNumber AS TargetPartNumber, COUNT(*) AS ItemCount
    FROM bom b1
    JOIN bom b2 ON b1.ItemNumber = b2.ItemNumber
                AND b1.Quantity = b2.Quantity
                AND b1.UnitID = b2.UnitID
                AND b1.PartNumber <> b2.PartNumber
    WHERE b1.PartNumber = @PartNumber
    GROUP BY b1.PartNumber, b2.PartNumber
    ) AS bom2 ON bom1.PartNumber = bom2.PartNumber
                AND bom1.ItemCount = bom2.ItemCount
WHERE bom1.ItemCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bom WHERE PartNumber = bom2.TargetPartNumber)
ORDER BY bom2.TargetPartNumber
```

You can put it into a stored procedure or function. `@PartNumber` represents the value you would pass to the function.

Comment: I subsequently discovered that this code doesn't suffice.  It's finds invalid matches when TargetPartNumber contains in its BOM all items found in PartNumber's BOM plus one or more additional items.  In that event they shouldn't be considered identical.

Comment: Your approach can be tweaked by adding a where clause: WHERE bom1.ItemCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bom WHERE PartNumber = bom2.TargetPartNumber)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full solution based on a modified version of bobs' answer:

```
DECLARE @PartNumber AS udt_PartNumber; SET @PartNumber = N'10012163';

SELECT DISTINCT bom2.TargetPartNumber
FROM
    (
    SELECT PartNumber, COUNT(*) AS ItemCount
    FROM Part.BillsOfMaterials
    WHERE PartNumber = @PartNumber
    GROUP BY PartNumber
    ) AS bom1
JOIN
    (
    SELECT b1.PartNumber, b2.PartNumber AS TargetPartNumber, COUNT(*) AS ItemCount
    FROM Part.BillsOfMaterials b1
    RIGHT JOIN Part.BillsOfMaterials b2 ON b1.ItemNumber = b2.ItemNumber
                AND b1.Quantity = b2.Quantity
                AND b1.UnitID = b2.UnitID
                AND b1.PartNumber <> b2.PartNumber
    WHERE b1.PartNumber = @PartNumber
    GROUP BY b1.PartNumber, b2.PartNumber
    ) AS bom2 ON bom1.PartNumber = bom2.PartNumber
                AND bom1.ItemCount = bom2.ItemCount
WHERE bom1.ItemCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Part.BillsOfMaterials WHERE PartNumber = bom2.TargetPartNumber)
ORDER BY bom2.TargetPartNumber
```

The only difference is the final WHERE clause which ensures that a match is not found if the target contains extra rows not present in the source part number's BOM.

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest what I did for my case.

For each BOM,
I used cursor in which I selected and concatenated all the fields that I needed to validate were identical into the same variable. I dumped this into a temp table and then I could compare the content of the concatenated strings to determinate if the BOMS were Identical.

PART 1 I CREATED A SP THAT ACTS AS A FUNCTION TO CONCAT THE FIELDS I WANT TO COMPARE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBOMItems_TEMP]( @ItemNo varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Part VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Qty VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @concatbom VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE curBom CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
     BOM_PART
,    Quantity
from Assembly ASS
INNER JOIN Revision REV ON REV.Id = ASS.RevisionID
        AND REV.Is_Latest = 'true'
WHERE ASS.Category = 'MyCat' AND Parent_Item_Number = @ItemNo
ORDER BY BOM_PART --IMPORTANT OR NO STRINGS WILL MATCH

OPEN curBom

FETCH NEXT FROM curBom INTO @Part, @Qty
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

 SELECT @concatbom = concat(@concatbom, @Part, @Qty);
FETCH NEXT FROM curBom INTO @Part, @Qty
END
CLOSE curBom
DEALLOCATE curBom

SELECT @ItemNo as [Item], @concatbom as ConcatBom
```

end

PART 2: I created another proc to execute the first proc for every Items that has BOMS and which I want to compare

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllConcatBoms
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE curItem CURSOR FOR SELECT [name]
FROM Items

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.ConcatBom', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].ConcatBom;
CREATE TABLE ConcatBom ( Item      varchar(100)
,                        ConcatBom varchar(max) )
OPEN curItem

FETCH NEXT FROM curItem INTO @Item
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO ConcatBom ( Item, ConcatBom )
    EXEC GetBOMItems_TEMP @ItemNo = @Item

    FETCH NEXT FROM curItem INTO @Item
END

CLOSE curItem
DEALLOCATE curItem
```

END

Part 3 : execute proc of part 2 and then select what you want to see

```
exec GetAllConcatBoms
SELECT * FROM ConcatBom ORDER BY CONCATBOM WHERE ITEM LIKE 
'%sampleitem%'
```

This code is not pretty but in my case I only needed to perform this once so I can sort the data I need to work with. I used SP and a Table because I knew I was going to delete those right after I am done. But the idea is the point here.

For each BOM concatenate the content each line item into a single string then compare the strings to find the matches.

My result would look like this:

| Assembly | ConcatPart&QtyFields |
| --- | --- |
| Bom1. | screw3.00bolt3.00label2.00etc3.00 |
| Bom2. | screw3.00bolt3.00label2.00etc3.00 |
| Bom3. | board1.00panel2.00label1.00chassis1.00ssd1.00 |

Now you can easily see that bom 1 and 2 are identical
And by ordering on the concat string they will all be grouped together.
Its easier to compare a single row than possibly hundreds.
Hope this helps someone.